# Decrypt and mount an eCryptFS encrypted directory using an external C++ script in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, mount, ecryptfs

I want to decrypt and mount the default eCryptfs private directory by executing the "ecryptfs-mount-private" terminal command in C++ and providing the passphrase/password from the same C++ script.

I have tried forking then exec the shell (/bin/sh) and opening pipes for I/O with sh but when I try to write through the pipe I get the following error:

> stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device

I guess this is because ecryptfs-mount-private only accepts input for a passphrase from the keyboard.

How can I achieve this type of decrypt and mount mechanism? Possible ways of doing this or any workarounds will be helpful.

PS. Security concern of storing the passphrase in the C++ code is not a problem in my scenario.

Thanks!

Comment: `ecryptfs-mount-private` is a script, and only about 65 lines without comments, you could try running the lines one at a time &/or "converting" some of it

Comment: @Xen2050 thanks a lot for the hint! I looked into the `ecryptfs-mount-private` script and figured out a method of decrypting and mounting the private directory. Basically `ecryptfs-mount-private` performed a number of steps. I executed those necessary steps in my C script using `system()` command.

Comment: That's good news. Several of the ecryptfs tools (and some other linux tools) are shell scripts that show a good "behind the scenes" look. I guess I should turn my comment into an answer, since it was helpful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ecryptfs-mount-private` is a `/bin/sh` shell script (and relatively short, only about 65 lines without comments) so you could try running "converting" some of it into C++ and/or running the remaining shell command lines one at a time with `system()`.

Answer (score -1):

`ecrypt-mountfs-private` expects to be attached to a terminal.
One solution is to use `forkpty`(2) instead of `fork`, which will ensure the child process has access to a pty (pseudo-tty). You can then write to and read from the master file descriptor to provide input resp. read output from the child process.

Comment: What's wrong with this answer? Does it not work? Why did someone downvote it?

Comment: @Botje thanks for the suggestion :) I tried this but couldn't get it to work exactly as I wanted because of some deadline constraints and my lack of knowledge in forkpty and file descriptors in general. However I was able to achieve the desired behavior using Xen2050's suggestion.